# How to specify ca_bundle in Kubernetes Python client

Tags: python, ssl, kubernetes

I am trying to use the [Kubernetes Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to connect to my Kubernetes cluster.  The API is behind an SSL certificate signed by my CA.  If I try to access any API, I get an SSL error about certificate verification failing.

I found a [v1beta1_api_service_spec.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/client/models/v1beta1_api_service_spec.py) library that has a parameter for ca_bundle to verify the certificate, but the [core_v1_api.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py) and [api_client.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/client/api_client.py) do not have parameter options for ca_bundle.

How do I pass the CA certificate so I can access the API over HTTPS?

### ** Solution **

Based on Matthew's pointer, I was able to figure out the problem.  Initially, I was using the Kubernetes config module to load the configuration from the ~/.kube/config file.

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
```

This wasn't working on the client I was testing on, but kubectl was working from my PC, so I checked, and found that the .kube/config file did not specify the CA cert.  I added it in, and then it worked.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    api-version: v1
    certificate-authority: /path/to/ca_chain.crt
    server: "https://my-kubernetes-cluster"
    ...
```

I also was able to figure out how to manually build the configuration if you do not want to create the .kube/config file on the host.

```
from kubernetes import client
from kubernetes.client import Configuration, ApiClient
config = Configuration()
config.api_key = {'authorization': 'Bearer <api_key>'}
config.host = 'https://my-kubernetes-cluster'
config.ssl_ca_cert = "/path/to/ca_chain.crt"

api_client = ApiClient(configuration=config)
v1 = client.CoreV1Api(api_client)

v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
```

Comment: where did you get the "/path/to/ca_chain.crt".mine is generated by kubectl

Comment: That path is where I have saved my certificate chain on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be two answers:

1. [the comment in RESTClientObject](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/v4.0.0/kubernetes/client/rest.py#L64) saying that they are using `urllib3` [and have a pointer to its documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#custom-ssl-certificates-and-client-certificates), meaning you could apparently make such a change at the level of the host OS
2. `RESTClientObject` [accepts kwargs](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/v4.0.0/kubernetes/client/rest.py#L73-L77) related to SSL management, including the ability to switch off SSL verification, if that interests you. The `configuration` variable mentioned is passed [directly from the ApiClient.__init__](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/v4.0.0/kubernetes/client/api_client.py#L62)